# The name 'ASCIIEncoding' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, sql, webmatrix

I'm trying to encrypt a string to save it in sql server database but "The name 'ASCIIEncoding' does not exist in the current context" shows up. How to encrypt strings in ASP.Net Web Pages Framework? Following is my code:

```
@using System.Security.Cryptography;
@{
String s = "hello";
String s2 = "hello";
s = Encrypt(s,_key);
s2 = Encrypt(s2, _key);
}

@functions{
private static readonly byte[] _key = "myVeryStrongPsw";


public static string Encrypt(string strToEncrypt, string strKey)
{
    try
    {
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider objDESCrypto =
            new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider objHashMD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] byteHash, byteBuff;
        string strTempKey = strKey;
        byteHash = objHashMD5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strTempKey));
        objHashMD5 = null;
        objDESCrypto.Key = byteHash;
        objDESCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; //CBC, CFB
        byteBuff = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToEncrypt);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(objDESCrypto.CreateEncryptor().
            TransformFinalBlock(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Wrong Input. " + ex.Message;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either reference `System.Text` with a `using` statement

```
using System.Text ;
```

or fully qualify the reference:

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
```

But you should realize that `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII` is...redundant. Just say

```
`System.Text.Encoding.ASCII`
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ASCIIEncoding` class is enclosed in the `System.Text` namespace. You will need to do one of two things:

- Add a `using` statement for the namespace (as in `using System.Text`)
- fully qualify the class name (as in `byteBuff = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToEncrypt);`)

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for additional information.